# Install two debug apk from same application (Flavors)

Tags: java, android, android-productflavors

So I have this app1 and I want to create a app2, from the app1, It will be almost the same app, but with differences in the layout. I manage to do that using productFlavors. The result need to be two apps in the Play store, both free and the user can have both in his phone.

However I can build both apk for debug, but when I install one, the phone doesn't let me install the other. Will this happen after both are uploaded to the store?

This is my gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 48
    versionName "3.1.1"

    multiDexEnabled true
}

signingConfigs {
    String releaseFilename = "/.androidReleaseKeys/example_release.properties"

    Properties props = new Properties()
    props.load(new FileInputStream(file(releaseFilename)))


    release {
        storeFile file(props.getProperty('keystore'))
        storePassword props.getProperty('keystore.password')
        keyAlias props.getProperty('keyAlias')
        keyPassword props.getProperty('keyAlias.password')
    }

}

productFlavors{
    app1{
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        buildTypes {

            debug {
                buildConfigField "String", "GOOGLEMAPS_API_KEY", "\"${googleMapsAPIDev}\"";
                debuggable true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }


            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                buildConfigField "String", "GOOGLEMAPS_API_KEY", "\"${googleMapsAPIRelease}\"";
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    app2{
        applicationId "com.example2.app2"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
        multiDexEnabled true

        buildTypes {

            debug {
                buildConfigField "String", "GOOGLEMAPS_API_KEY", "\"${googleMapsAPIDev}\"";
                debuggable true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }


            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                buildConfigField "String", "GOOGLEMAPS_API_KEY", "\"${googleMapsAPIRelease}\"";
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Should I create now a new app in console, and create a new keystore just for her? (I read somewhere that you can use the same keystore for more than one app)

Comment: What error is returned by `adb` when you install the second app?

Comment: Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION perm=com.example1.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE pkg=com.example2.app (not in adb just a pop up) I guess i need to create a second manifest and merge with some changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare this permission in manifest with `${applicationId}` placeholder:

```
<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<permission
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

Do not hardcode package name in manifest.

Comment: I'm trying that, but what about the package field in manifest, it's seems that I use ${applicationId} the adb says it cannot read packageName

Comment: How do you set package in manifest? Post your `<manifest>` tag.

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example1.com"> i left like this but changed the hard coded in the rest of the manifest and it worked, I have now the two apps installed. Thank you, I accepted your answer